# How to synthesize a material at 2000 atmosphers?

Tags: pressure, experimental-technology

I am trying to combine various elements and at high pressure, e.g. $2000\,\mathrm{atm}$ or $2 \cdot {10}^{8} \, \mathrm{Pa}?$

How could these pressures be achieved for a gas with a volume of about $1\,\mathrm{cm}^3?$

Comment: This does strike me as a question better asked on Chemistry SE.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98205/how-to-synthesize-a-material-at-2000atmospheres

Comment: High pressure physics and geophysics folks would be the people to ask. High pressure gas cells and diamond anvils (although not a cc) are several options.

Comment: what temperature are you planning to operate at? that will dramatically effect the options available to you.

Comment: [This compressor](https://www.burckhardtcompression.com/solution/compressor-technologies/hyper-compressor/), maybe?

Comment: @Ummdustry Temperature would be just over 800 centigrade.